# How to reduce CPU usage when it reaches 100% while converting video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

We are use ffmpeg for convert video to a specific form. The server is reaching 100% CPU usage, so my site is going down. That means the ffmpeg process has a strong effect on my main server.

[image]

Comment: Are you running ffmpeg on the server itself, or does the server only holds the files?

Comment: If you show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete log from the command we may be able to make more suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a small server with 4 GB RAM and a virtual dual-core CPU that is most likely using shared resources. Obviously, this machine is not going to be able to handle video encoding tasks *and* serve a website at the same time, unless you make compromises in terms of the time it takes for the video encoding to complete.

Under Linux, you can run [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) to reduce the priority of a process.

For example, run:

```
nice ffmpeg -i <input> <output>
```

The "niceness" values range from -20 to 19, and the higher, the lower priority a process gets. Without further options, `nice` adds 10 to the value of the process, which is 0 by default.

That said, I'd encourage you to not run web servers and intensive processing tasks on the same machine unless you can compartmentalize them in such a way that high resource consumption doesn't kill your website.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to slhck's suggestion of using `nice` you can limit encoding threads with the `-threads` option if `nice` is not nice enough.

Another option is to offload the encoding to hardware, such as nvenc, if it is supported by your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter: `-threads 1` for less CPU core.